# How can I create a microsoft azure ad user with 'mail' populated through azure or unified graph apis?

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, azure-ad-graph-api

I am trying to populate an azure active directory with users using the create endpoints in either the graph.microsoft.com or graph.windows.net apis.

The issue I'm having is that I cannot populate the 'mail' property; Is there a way to create users or update users to have an email?

```
POST /beta/myorganization/users HTTP/1.1
Content-Type: application/json
Host: graph.microsoft.com
Connection: close
{
  "accountEnabled": true,
  "displayName": "Ham Sandwhich",
  "mailNickname": "test-ad-1-1",
  "passwordProfile": {
    "password": "allthegoodthings"
  },
  "userPrincipalName": "test-ad-1-1@orgname.onmicrosoft.com"
}
```

responds with

```
HTTP/1.1 400 Bad Request
Cache-Control: private
Transfer-Encoding: chunked
Content-Type: application/json
Server: Microsoft-IIS/8.5
request-id: c954b6f0-9ac1-4354-b27d-88b0d89becfb
client-request-id: c954b6f0-9ac1-4354-b27d-88b0d89becfb
x-ms-ags-diagnostic: {"ServerInfo":{"DataCenter":"West US","Slice":"SliceB","ScaleUnit":"000","Host":"AGSFE_IN_4","ADSiteName":"WST"}}
Duration: 175.0114
X-Powered-By: ASP.NET
Date: Wed, 13 Jul 2016 23:12:28 GMT
Connection: close

{
  "error": {
    "code": "Request_BadRequest",
    "message": "Property 'mail' is read-only and cannot be set.",
    "innerError": {
      "request-id": "c954b6f0-9ac1-4354-b27d-88b0d89becfb",
      "date": "2016-07-13T23:12:28"
    }
  }
}
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the response, you can't. An alternative is to set the field otherMails

```
{
  "accountEnabled": true,
  "displayName": "Gabriel Ferrarini",
  "mailNickname": "GabrielFerrarini",
  "passwordProfile": {
    "password": "Test1234",
    "forceChangePasswordNextLogin": false
  },
  "otherMails": [
        "myemail@myhost.com"
      ],
  "userPrincipalName": "GabrielFerrarini@mytenant.onmicrosoft.com"
}
```

Comment: But it can be set if I do so manually, right? So there ought to be some api that can do it.

Comment: Nevermind, it looks like mail really is only set through exchange or on-prem sync

Comment: You may send the mail using the Microsoft Graph REST directly as a workaround. Or you can submit the feedback [here](https://officespdev.uservoice.com/) if you require this feature.

Comment: For those reading this now, what @FeiXue-MSFT said no longer holds true. Graph will return "Property 'mail' is read-only and cannot be set."